# How to prevent objects used by threads from being disposed? How to control the lifetime of the object?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, com

Consider we have C# and C++ talking via COM.
Inside C++ we have two classes named **ProcessText** and **Text**.

**Text Class:**
Holds the Text details object like string, numberOfPages, etc

**ProcessText Class:** 
It reads the files in the given input directory and process the files using C# component with the help of 2 functions

**ReadAll() Method:**
It reads all the file in the directory creates Text object and passes it down to ProcessAll().

**ProcessAll() Method:**
Consider MultiThreading Scenario where the input Text object to C# component is fed to the threads.

Inside ProcessAll() the scope of the Text object is finished I need some mechanism to prevent the object from going out of scope until the thread finishes the processing and if this is not possible at least trigger C#  component to stop processing on that Text Object.

> What I specifically wants can it be achieved by using Destructor of
>   C++ class?  If during destruction of Text Object we query C# component
>   about the status of the Text object and can we block its memory from
>   destruction without waiting on the thread to complete operation?  Also
>   if the object is not destroyed but still the memory will be freed. Can
>   we prevent the memory from getting freed? If memory still holds value
>   as memory leak can it be used by threads safely and also can it be
>   taken up the OS to write some other things? If it can be taken up by
>   the OS can we block this memory by using pointer and size of the
>   object?

Comment: How big is the Text object?  Can't you just make a copy of it?

Comment: You've only documented an imaginary problem, memory management in a C# program is automatic.  Your C++ destructor cannot run until the RCW for your COM object gets collected and finalized.  That can't happen until the C# code no longer has a live reference to the object.

Comment: @Robinson Text object is only an example based on this I have to scale up .. we can consider object to be minimum 100MBs of data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, all you have to do in C# is `GC.KeepAlive(text)` at the end of the thread.

If that is not enough (e.g. because you need to keep those `Text` objects alive until after all threads have finished their job), then you must keep a reference to the `Text` objects.  Perhaps the easiest way to achieve this is to use PLINQ, e.g. `files.AsParallel().Select(...).ToList()` (or `SelectMany(...)`).

This way, by the end of the parallel enumeration, you'll have references to all `Text` objects, assuming that's what you'll return from `Select` (or `SelectMany`).  You then need to control for how long you need to reference the new enumerable, e.g. you may have to use `GC.KeepAlive(texts)` at the end of the `ProcessAll()` method.